# How to use MockHttpServletRequest and MockHttpSession to test an application using Spring 6 and running on TomEE 9

Tags: spring, maven, servlets, maven-surefire-plugin, apache-tomee

Migrating from (Tomee 8, Spring 5) to (Tomee 9, Spring 6) I am facing an issue running my tests because of `MockHttpServletRequest` importing Servlet 6.0.0 class `jakarta.servlet.ServletConnection` triggering the exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/servlet/ServletConnection` at test runtime.

Tomee 9 is based on Tomcat 10.0 and Jakarta 9.1, therefore providing Servlet 5.0 version.

Spring Framework [wiki](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#javajakarta-ee-versions) says:

> As of Spring Framework 6.0, the minimum is Jakarta EE 9 (Servlet 5.0, JPA 3.0, Bean Validation 3.0), with the latest Jakarta EE 10 (Servlet 6.0, JPA 3.1) recommended.

"[What's new in Spring 6.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-6.x)" also says:

> Alignment with Servlet 6.0 (while retaining runtime compatibility with Servlet 5.0).

But at the same time `MockHttpServletRequest` javadoc says :

> As of Spring 6.0, this set of mocks is designed on a Servlet 6.0 baseline.

And it is confirmed by "[Upgrading to Spring 6.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#web-applications)" wiki:

> The Spring-provided Servlet mocks (MockHttpServletRequest, MockHttpSession) require Servlet 6.0 now, due to a breaking change between the Servlet 5.0 and 6.0 API jars. They can be used for testing Servlet 5.0 based code but need to run against the Servlet 6.0 API (or newer) on the test classpath. Note that your production code may still compile against Servlet 5.0 and get integration-tested with Servlet 5.0 based containers; just mock-based tests need to run against the Servlet 6.0 API jar.

So, I can use Spring 6 on a Tomee 9 server but I cannot use MockHttpServletRequest, MockHttpSession in my tests.

My project is a Maven 3 project with the dependency :

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-bom</artifactId>
  <version>9.1.0</version>
  <scope>import</scope>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

I'm able to run my tests if I override the Servlet version :

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.0.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

However I don't consider that as a safe solution since new code (from our code base or from a dependency) might use undetected Servlet 6.x only features until crashing at runtime once deployed on Tomee 9.

Alternatives are:

- Migrating to Tomcat 10.1 instead of Tomee 9 since it supports Servlet 6.0,
- Refactor my tests to avoid using MockHttpServletRequest and MockHttpSession,
- Find a way to "trick" Maven (maven surefire plugin) into using Servlet 6.x version while running tests only.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you will use `jakarta.servlet-api` just with the `provided` scope, this should work for real Servlet containers but for mocked Servlet tests try to change the scope `provided` for the artifact `jakarta.servlet-api` to the scope `test` for actually having the new Servlet API 6 at running tests

Comment: Do you mean using something like a property to switch the scope for the tests ? Or have two declarations of `jakarta.servlet-api`, one with scope `provided` version 5.0.0 and one with scope `test` version 6.0.0 ?

Comment: Only once with the test scope (test scope already implies provided)

Comment: But if I set the scope to `test` I'll have compilation errors in my "main" code using `jakarta.servlet-api`classes.
Also, it doesn't solve the initial issue, I have to use Servlet 5.0 to be compatible with Tomee 9 / Tomcat 10.0, therefore I cannot use Spring 6 'MockHttpServletRequest' requiring Servlet 6.X.